# Rails nesting associations with first_or_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through, has-many

I have a `comic_books` table which has many issues, each of which has an `author and illustrator`, currently stored as strings only. Using `has_many:through` for comic_books to issues works great, and now I'm trying to figure out how to add associations for the author and illustrator.

The problem is that the author and illustrator are sometimes the same person. If you click an illustrator I'd like to see the specific issues he/she has written OR illustrated. If I setup a `has_one belongs_to association` I'll only get the volumes results of either illustration OR author, but I want both from the same "creator".

So that lead me to trying out a `creator` table, but I can't figure out how to place the associations. I'd like a creator table that stores the `name`, and a `creator_id` in both writers and illustrators.

Then I'd like to call

```
issue.illustrator.first_or_create!('bob smith')
```

But that's not right. 
I don't want independent illustrators and writers table since they will have the same names in each. I need to abstract it out further, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I think I want to make a new creator record if one does not exist and store `creator_id` into the illustrator table so that I can reference issue.illustrator.name, but the name value is actually in the creator table...

Is there simply a better way to do the task overall?

Comment: The more I think about it  the more I want to use the words "IS a" instead of "HAS a".  A writer IS a creator, not has many...

But I haven't learned anything about creating custom rails inheritance yet, is that correct or over-thinking it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to your attempt to assign an illustrator, you'd probably want to do something like this instead:

```
issue.illustrator = Illustrator.first_or_create(name: "Bob Smith")
```

depending on what model you were using. I got a little bit lost with what models you have and how you're structuring their associations towards the end there.

The way I would probably deal with this situation would be to use a `Creator` class for both authors and illustrators, and use a third, cross-reference model (call, for example, `Involvement`) to link it to specific `Issues`, and specify what their role was in that third model. The associations would look like this (ignoring `Comic`, since it sounds like you track the author/illustrator by `Issue`):

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :involvements
  has_many :creators, through: :involvements
  ...
end

class Creator < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :involvements
  has_many :issues, through: :involvements
  ...
end

class Involvement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :issue
  belongs_to :creator

  # This model would then have an extra property to store the type of involvement
  # ie. author, illustrator, author/illustrator
  attr_accessible :type, ...
end
```

(My inclination would be to make the `type` property on `Involvement` a bit-masked integer, so it might be `1` for author, `2` for illustrator, and `3` for author/illustrator.)

This way, you could add a `Creator` to an `Issue` with the following:

```
inv = Issue.involvements.create(type: ...) # Whatever's appropriate
inv.creator = Creator.find_or_create('Bob Smith')
```

Comment: I did try a "creatorship" :through association on the creators model, but when I tried to create it using issue.illustrator = Creator.find_or_create I got a class mismatch error.

But I think I see how you're passing it from another instance, I didn't think of that. I was trying to nest further (comic.issue.illustrator.creator) instead of simply creating the association directly... awesome! I'll test it out tomorrow!

Comment: I ended up just creating a HABTM association between the issues and a creator table, passing along the writer_id, artist_id, etc. Seems pretty clean on the DB side, very sloppy on the view and model. I posted a new question as a followup. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961029/refactor-association-out-of-view-from-a-loop

Comment: Ah, I think I see how you've gone about it, using `artist_id` etc. as properties of the `issue`, right? That works too. The one thing you'll lose doing it that way is it'll be a little more convoluted to look at a creator's works and see whether they were an artist or author or whatever, but that may be a priority for you :) I'll have a look at your other question and see if I can offer any help.