# Refactor association out of view from a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, associations

Just getting started in rails and trying to refactor down a bit of my view, and I'm a bit stumped as to where to go for the answer since I'm inside an each loop I need access to the |item|.

I'm pulling the writer from a CSV file, using a creator table and a HABTM assocation with books. The reason is sometimes the writer is also the illustrator and also the editor, I didn't want 3 (and more maybe) tables for each specific role of a book author.

Books Model ( with CSV import )

```
    writer = Creator.where(name: row['writer']).first_or_create!(row.to_hash.slice(:writer))
    book.creators << writer
    book.writer_id = writer.id
```

Book View

```
   books.each do |book|
     link_to book.creators.detect{|w| w.id == book.writer_id}.name, creator_path(id: book.writer_id)
```

And then I duplicate that for artist, editor, etc...

I first tried a @books in the controller, but I need to know which book from the loop. I'm not sure the next step to learn about so I can remove the ugly. I've seen lots of things I want to go read up on, but not sure which suits this need. Helpers? Named scopes?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're having? It's somewhat vague in the question.

Comment: It's not quite a problem if the app works the way I want, but it seems like I'm not doing something right compared to how simple most everything else is. 

Being that I'm just starting I'm trying to learn best practices and there's a lot of repetition in both the model and view, but I don't know what to change to make it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the complexity here is introduced by the fact by using `writer_id` etc. instead of an actual association, which would probably make things a little bit easier. If you're going to stick with your current structure though, what you have is probably pretty close to what you want, although you may want to change that `link_to` line to the more simple:

```
link_to book.creators.find(book.writer_id).name, creator_path(book.writer_id)
```

Another option would be to setup custom getter method for writer and illustrator in your model, which would let you simplify things even more:

```
# book.rb
def writer
  creators.find(writer_id) # This should allow you to still eager load it if you want
end

def illustrator
  creators.find(illustrator_id)
end

# in your view
link_to book.writer.name, creator_path(book.writer_id)
```

(You could also write setter methods, although this would be a little bit more complex, and possibly not worth it unless you're planning on changing the creators.)

Comment: The getter looks very nice, thanks! I'll definitely need to look more into ruby classes in general aside from rails.

What would an actual association entail? I'm using a books_creators table to associate the books and creators, but I needed some way to identify which creator has which role on each book. As :through association with "creatorship" or something didn't quite seem to make sense to me.